# Como substituir variáveis com valores NEGATIVOS por ZERO dentro de um data.frame no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Digamos que tenho um data.frame 6x5, exemplo:

```
print(Dados)

Linha  A   B   C   D   E
L1     4   3  -1   2   4
L2     1  -2   1  -5   1
L3    -1  -1   2   3   4
L4     2   4   5  -7   9
```

Mas quero substituir os valores Negativos do data.frame por Zeros, exemplo:

```
Linha  A   B   C   D   E
L1     4   3   0   2   4
L2     1   0   1   0   1
L3     0   0   2   3   4
L4     2   4   5   0   9
```

Como posso fazer para substituir as variáveis com valores NEGATIVOS por ZERO dentro do meu data.frame?

**Dados.**

```
Dados <- read.table(text = "
Linha  A   B   C   D   E
L1     4   3  -1   2   4
L2     1  -2   1  -5   1
L3    -1  -1   2   3   4
L4     2   4   5  -7   9
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Porquê fechar? Esta pergunta é sobre programação e até pode ter respostas só em R base ou com o pacote `dplyr`.

Comment: Se não se importar com o warning a maneira mais simples q existe é `Dados[Dados<0] <- 0`ele vai substituir tudo que for negativo por `0` vai acontecer um warning pq seu `data.frame`não está todo em números, tem strings no meio ...

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio @Rui Barradas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eis mais uma maneira, com o pacote `dplyr`. Utiliza o `mutate_if` (`mutate` condicional) para determinar quais colunas são numéricas e modifica só essas colunas. A função `neg2zero` serve para tornar o código mais legível.

```
library(dplyr)

neg2zero <- function(x) {
  x[x < 0] <- 0
  x
}

Dados %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, neg2zero)
#  Linha A B C D E
#1    L1 4 3 0 2 4
#2    L2 1 0 1 0 1
#3    L3 0 0 2 3 4
#4    L4 2 4 5 0 9
```

Agora que a ideia principal está mostrada, pode-se usar uma função anónima.

```
Dados %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) {x[x < 0] <- 0; x})
#  Linha A B C D E
#1    L1 4 3 0 2 4
#2    L2 1 0 1 0 1
#3    L3 0 0 2 3 4
#4    L4 2 4 5 0 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Só com `R base` é possível fazer isso.

Vou apresentar duas soluções com uso de `ifelse`:

```
data_1 <- sapply(X = Dados[c(2:6)], FUN = function(x) {
  ifelse(test = x < 0, 0, x)
})

data_1

     A B C D E
[1,] 4 3 0 2 4
[2,] 1 0 1 0 1
[3,] 0 0 2 3 4
[4,] 2 4 5 0 9
```

Note que neste caso é preciso saber os índices dos vetores dentro do `data.frame`. Ou seja, tem de fazer isso: `X = Dados[c(2:6)]`.

Mas, suponha que você queira substituir por zeros apenas das variáveis que tenham uma determinada classe, como `integer` (vetor de números inteiros). Com `rapply` você faz isso:

```
data_2 <- rapply(object = Dados, classes = 'integer', how = 'replace', f = function(x) {
  ifelse(test = x < 0, 0, x)
})

data_2

  Linha A B C D E
1    L1 4 3 0 2 4
2    L2 1 0 1 0 1
3    L3 0 0 2 3 4
4    L4 2 4 5 0 9
```

Uma solução mais simples, se você sabe que a primeira variável não é númerica, é esta:

```
Dados[-1][Dados[-1] < 0] <- 0
Dados

  Linha A B C D E
1    L1 4 3 0 2 4
2    L2 1 0 1 0 1
3    L3 0 0 2 3 4
4    L4 2 4 5 0 9
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou testar.

Comment: `-c(1)` e `-1` são o mesmo vetor, a segunda forma é mais simples.